# What characters are there past end of file?

Tags: c, file

I'm relatively new to C, my question is:

Is it ALWAYS true that there are only EOF chars past the end of a file?

Example code:

```
FILE *fr;
int i;

fr=fopen("file.txt","r");

for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
    putchar(getc(fr));
}

fclose(fr);
```

Output:

```
user@host:~$ ./a.out | xxd
0000000: 6173 640a ffff ffff ffff                 asd.......
```

(`file.txt` contains `asd\n`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer: there aren't **any** characters beyond the end of a file. My MSVC manual page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5231d02a.aspx) says that if you read past the end of the file, `getc()` returns `EOF`.

It does not matter how many times you try to make `getc()` read past the end of the file, it won't. It just keeps returning `EOF`.

The `EOF` is not part of the file marking its end - it is a flag value returned by `getc()` to tell you there is no more data.

**EDIT** included a sample to show the behaviour of `feof()`. Note, I made separate `printf()` statements, rather than merging them into a single statement, because it is important to be clear what order the functions `feof()` and `getc()` are called.

Note that `feof()` does not return a non-0 value until *after* `getc()` returned `EOF`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fr;
    int i;
    fr=fopen("file.txt","r");
    for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
        printf("feof=%04X, ", feof(fr));
        printf("getc=%04X\n", getc(fr));
    }
    fclose(fr);
}
```

Program input file:

```
abc\n
```

Program output:

```
feof=0000, getc=0061
feof=0000, getc=0062
feof=0000, getc=0063
feof=0000, getc=000A
feof=0000, getc=FFFFFFFF
feof=0010, getc=FFFFFFFF
```

So, you can't use `feof()` to tell you the end of file was reached. It tells that you made a read error *after* reaching the end of file.

Comment: Although `putchar()` takes an `int` argument, only the lower 8 bits are written out. On my Windows console `0xFF` is a non-printing char, but if I redirect the output to a file I can see the `0xFF` values.

Comment: Thanks, is it true that a file can contain embedded EOF? I know that I can use feof, but is it the `FF` byte then?

Comment: On Windows, you *can* put an embedded EOF character in a **text** file. However, the embedded end-of-file is a ctrl-Z character, decimal 26. On *nix systems, there is no way to embed an EOF in the file itself.

Comment: @Mike of course it can, but `EOF` is an `int` value. It won't be read as `EOF` - each component byte will be read individually as `0xFF`. But also, text files used to contain an end of file marker, such as Ctrl-Z (`0x1A`) but I don't think that's relevant to the question. As for `feof()` - use it at your peril as it is one of the most misunderstood functions in C.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why? Is it dangerous to use?

Comment: @mike you mean `feof()`? Dangerous only when used incorrectly. It does *not* tell you the file pointer is at EOF. It tells you you made a **bad read** beyond the end of the file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong You can check it out yourself by printing its value as a second statement in your `for` loop.

Comment: @user3386109 The ctrl-Z EOF char you mention is, even on Windows, still different from the EOF value returned from eg. `getc()`

Comment: @Dmitri Yes, but if you put a ctrl-Z in a text file on Windows, then `getc` will start returning `EOF` when it reaches that point in the file.

Comment: @mike I expanded my answer to show how `feof()` behaves.

Answer (score 4):

There are no `EOF` characters in a file, nor any characters after the end of a file (it's the end of the file, after all). Rather, `EOF` is a special value used by [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) (and others) to indicate that there isn't anything to read. You can use [`feof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) and [`ferror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror) to see whether that `EOF` was caused by reaching the end of the file, or if an error ocurred.

What you are seeing are the `EOF` values ([cast to an `unsigned char`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc)) that `getc` returned after reaching the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, there aren't "EOF chars" in the file to mark the end.  `EOF` is just an integer value, that does not correspond to a valid `char` value, that is returned by some functions when there's *nothing* left in the file.

In your example, you see the `ff` values after the contents of the file because when `getc()` returns EOF, indicating there's nothing left to read, you're displaying it as a `char`... effectively displaying the `char` corresponding to the low bits of the EOF value and ignoring the high bits.  If you read the file in a different way, you might not see that result.